# Bitwise operator in the definition of hashCode() in HashMap

Tags: java

I am trying to understand what this is doing exactly, when I was reading the definition of hashCode() in hashMap in Java:

```
public final int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(key) ^ Objects.hashCode(value); }
```

I was reading ^ is a bitwise exclusive OR, and Objects.hashCode(key), Objects.hashCode(value) both return an Integer. So does it mean it is converting the two integers to two binary numbers like 10101010111, 1111000  and then apply the ^ operation at the same corresponding position of the two numbers? If one number is shorter than the other, what does it do? Or if both numbers are the same length, what does it do?

I am kind of confused about what hashCode() do exactly. I am asking this question based on the reading that we sometimes have to override equals when using a Map, and when override equals we also have to worry about override Hashcode, is it true?

Comment: the "what does it do?" is simple to find out if you would try? you also ask many questions at the same time

Comment: All `int`s have the same size in Java (4 bytes). So the exclusive or works bit by bit for each position in the two integers. If *one number is shorter* then it is like being padded with most significant zeros.

Comment: You can look up both exclusive OR and hashCode on Wiki and get a complete answer for both.  And also look up HashTable.  Or search this site for existing answers.

Comment: It doesn't have to *convert* the numbers to binary. Computers store numbers in binary.

Comment: Yes, you should always override `equals` and `hashCode` when you override one of them, which is when you want to use your objects as hash keys and / or in equality comparisons. See Effective Java. Project Lombok can generate these for you.

Comment: Don't forget the documentation on [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) and [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So does it mean it is converting the two integers to two binary numbers like 10101010111, 1111000 and then apply the ^ operation at the same corresponding position of the two numbers?

There's no "convert". Binary is simply a different way to represent the same number. `0b00011011` and `27` are *the same*, just represented differently. The computer stores that number as the byte `00011011`, and then when we tell the computer to show us, it shows us in decimal instead of binary because that's easier for us.

When the computer does bitwise operations, it will do them in binary. Saying `0b00011011 ^ 0b00001101 = 0b00010110` is the same as saying `27 ^ 13 = 22`.

---

> If one number is shorter than the other, what does it do? or if both numbers are the same length, what does it do?

`int`s are always the same length (4 bytes). If an int's value doesn't fill up all 32 bits, then there are leading zeroes.

The full representation of `int x = 22` would be

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00010110
```

---

> I am kind of confused about what hashCode() do exactly. I am asking this question based on the reading that we sometimes have to override equals when using a Map, and when override equals we also have to worry about override Hashcode, is it true?

`hashCode()` distills the complicated value of an Object into a simple number. The rule is that:

```
a.equals(b)       -->      a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()
                implies
```

but not necessarily the reverse (after all, `hashCode()` returns an `int`, and there are a finite amount of numbers that fit in 32 bits - it's possible that two complex objects, like strings, hash to the same integer).

What hashtables (e.g. `HashMap`) do is use an key's `.hashCode()` to place it into a specific memory offset, such that it can be retrieved very quickly by knowing that offset. There are sometimes collisions, when multiple objects in the map have the same hash, but this drastically cuts down on the number of equality comparisons we have to do.

The alternative would be, for example, a `TreeMap`, which stores objects in a binary tree instead of a hash table. This is slower to retrieve objects from, because Java needs to call `.compareTo()` many times while we filter through memory, as opposed to in a `HashMap` where Java can usually call `.hashCode()` once and know exactly where to go.